# @ElementCollection of Enum in Embeddable

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, enums

I'm trying to use an elementCollection in an embeddable but JPA2.0 seems to ignore it.

If I go in debug I see that the collection in the embeddable is filled but it doesn't get persisted and JPA doesn't throw any exceptions. It just seems to ignore it for some reason I can't find.

If I place that elementCollection in the base entity (containing the embeddable), then the collection IS saved.

Why is this? How could I change that?

Code example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name =  "PRELEVATION_SURVEY")
public class PrelevationSurvey extends Domain {

    @Embedded
    private GeneralPatientInformation generalPatientInformation;

}

@Embeddable
public class GeneralPatientInformation {

    @ElementCollection(
        fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "CAUSES_OF_DEATH",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "SURVEY_ID"))
    @Column(name = "CAUSE_OF_DEATH")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private List<CauseOfDeath> causesOfDeath;

}
```

And again.. The causes of death ARE persisted if I place them on PrelevationSurvey but not if I place them in the embedabble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it with the following code:

```
public PrelevationSurvey save(PrelevationSurvey prelevationSurvey) {
    PrelevationSurvey attachedPrelevationSurvey = super.save(prelevationSurvey);
    attachedPrelevationSurvey.getGeneralPatientInformation().setCausesOfDeath(prelevationSurvey.getGeneralPatientInformation().getCausesOfDeath());
    return attachedPrelevationSurvey;
}
```

The save method calls "entityManager.merge(entity)".
I'm doing the merge of the collection myself.

Also see: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6143